# Unzipping values inside list comprehension

Tags: python

I want to do the following:

```
A, B = [[x, y] for (x, y) in Z]
```

desiring an output:

```
A = [x1, x2, ...] # xN are the N x values in Z
B = [y1, y2, ...]
```

There is the obvious solution to do:

```
A, B = [x for (x, y) in Z], [y for (x, y) in Z]
```

but the actual code has a pretty big list comprehension with some conditions inside, so it should be kept that way to not only save lines of code (and performance!) but also achieve the desired program behaviour (actual current code only retrieves `x for (x, y) in Z` and assigns it to `A`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A, B = zip(*([x, y] for (x, y) in Z))
```

Should work. Depending on the type of Z, you could probably get away with:

```
A, B = zip(*Z)
```

Comment: This is better written as just `A, B = zip(*Z)`

Comment: @lvc That's in my answer, and the OP mentioned that their list comprehension has more conditions than shown, thus the longer version.

Comment: Very well! But as I said, there are multiple conditions inside the list comprehension that are carefully placed to only be evaluated if necessary, so I need to mention x and y, still.

Comment: This fails when Z is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you say there are multiple, possibly complex, conditions, then remember that using a for-loop may be more adapted.

```
A = []
B = []
for x, y in Z:
    if conditon_on_x:
        A.append(x)
    if condition_on_y:
        B.append(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip by using zip, by expanding the variable like *zip(*var)*:

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 4)]
>>> alpha, num = zip(*list_of_tuples)
>>> print(alpha)
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
>>> print(num)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This works because *zip(*list_of_tuples)* is expanded to *zip( ('a',0), ('b',1), ('c',2), ('d',3), ('e',4) )*, and zip zips all those tuples together, resulting, ironically enough, in an unzip.

But I don't think doing this with a single list comprehension is actually possible, sorry!

Comment: wowserx' answer also works and allows me to fulfil my problem's constraints, as well :)

Comment: The other answer is actually equivalent to mine. I just explained how it works.

Comment: In my case, `x, y` and `Z` are closely related, so the code's purpose is easily understandable. Although it is true that often times the shorter code isn't the most appropriate one.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment after I reread his answer. wowserx's one-liner just constructs the list instead of using a variable, but the unzipping method is the same.